# iOS 9: Unwanted margin in UINavigationBar landscape

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, margin, uibarbuttonitem, ios9

There is a customized navigation bar and it worked perfectly until iOS 9.
Strange margin appears in landscape mode.

[image]

Standard code is used to create this layout.

```
- (UIBarButtonItem*)leftMenuButton {
    UIButton *menuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [menuBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIView *backArea = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, menuBtn.frame.size.width, menuBtn.frame.size.height)];
    [backArea addSubview:menuBtn];

//layer border are enabled just for issue visualization    
    backArea.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    backArea.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    menuBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    menuBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2;

    UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backArea];
    return backItem;
}
```

Comment: set constraints to menuBtn.

Comment: this is very old project, it doesn't use autolayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just stumbled upon this too. Navigation bars in iOS 9 have misaligned content when the device is in landscape mode. It looks like bar content is positioned so that it fits `Compact` metrics even though the bar still uses `Default` metrics (when used outside of `UINavigationController` for example). Looks like bars are somehow coupled screen orientation. What a mess.

**Edit:** Opened radar #23027275.